# Overriding Docker ENTRYPOINT in Kubernetes

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes

I have a Docker image of a Spring Boot app running in Kubernetes cluster. I'm trying to override an entrypoint.

My original entrypoint was

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/myapp-exec.jar"]
```

So I tried to override it in spec of deployment because I need to pass some JVM arguments:

```
      command: ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app/myapp-exec.jar ${0} ${@}"]
      args:
        - --spring[0].property=property_value
      env:
        - name: "JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "...jvm options..."
        - name: spring.property1
          value: property_value
        - name: spring.property2
          value: property_value
```

My application is launched, but properties defined under env that used to get passed to Spring app with original entry point are not passed anymore. According to [Spring Docker documentation](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/), ${0} ${@} should fix my exact issue, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the various shell-quoting problems by making the main container process a very short shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /myapp-exec.jar "$@"
```

Then your Dockerfile can specify this script as the main container command, instead of trying to shoehorn it into the `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` split somehow.

```sh
COPY run-myapp.sh .
CMD ["./run-myapp.sh"]  # (I tend to prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT)
```

If the only things you're trying to pass as command-line arguments are Spring properties, you can [specify those as environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding); this is much easier than trying to figure out the command-line setup.  So for your use case, I would specify

```yaml
containers:
  - name: myapp
    image: registry.example.com/myapp:20211203
    # neither command: nor args:
    env:
      - name: "JAVA_OPTS"
        value: "...jvm options..."
      - name: SPRING_PROPERTY1
        value: property_value
      - name: SPRING_PROPERTY2
        value: property_value
      - name: SPRING_0_PROPERTY
        value: property_value
```

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid the change of an entry point from inside the Dockerfile, at least during the test phase, but I suppose I don't have a choice.

Comment: I'm having problems with exec, it says `exec user process caused: no such file or directory`. Environment seems fine, ./bin is in it and therefore sh. Java is also set up correctly. BTW, I have to use args, there are some properties that use [] and I can't put those in env, it doesn't like it. Says the characters are not allowed. I managed to get everything to run with the same thing you've done, except calling `bin/sh -c` instead of `exec`, but args didn't work and container wouldn't run because of them. I guess they wouldn't with exec either, come to think of it.